# MFA Authentication Provider for ADFS 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, adfs2.0, adfs2.1

I don't seem to find information specifically for implementing an authentication-provider for ADFS 2.0 (and 2.1).

I already implemented an MFA authentication-provider for ADFS 3.0 using C# - that was a really smooth process, implementing some interfaces of `Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web`. But I don't see any docs for this on ADFS 2.x.

Any ideas or experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFA and all the extra claims (and claims engine instances) were new in ADFS on Windows Server 2012R2. It did not exist in earlier versions.

Comment: is there any way to make MFA work on ADFS 1.x and 2.x?